# Recursively enable children nodes xml groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file:

```
<testItems>
<children>
<testItem name=TestSuite1 enabled=false>
    <children>
        <testItem name=test1 enabled=false>
        </testItem>
        <testItem name=test2 enabled=false>
        </testItem>
        <testItem name=test3 enabled=false>
        </testItem>
    </children>
</testItem>
<testItem name=TestSuite2 enabled=false>
    <children>
        <testItem name=test3 enabled=false>
        </testItem>
        <testItem name=test4 enabled=false>
        </testItem>
        <testItem name=test5 enabled=false>
        </testItem>
    </children>
</testItem>
```

The structure can change(meaning the depth of the tree can change).

I want to enable TestSuite1 and by that recursively enable all children of TestSuite1 (test1, test2, test3)

So far I have:

```
def root = new XmlParser(false, false, true).parse(mdsFile)

 root.depthFirst().each {
                if (it.@name == testItemToEnable) {
                    it.@enabled = true
                    it.children.depthFirst().each { child ->
                    child.@enabled = true
                }
            }
```

but I have the following exception:

```
 No signature of method: groovy.util.NodeList.depthFirst() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

[ADDED AFTER QUESTION IN COMMENTS]

```
<testItems>
<children>
<testItem name="TestSuite1" enabled="false">
  <children>
    <testItem name="test1" enabled="false">
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="test2" enabled="false">
    <children>
        <testItem name="testX" enabled="false">
    </testItem>
    </children>
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="test3" enabled="false">
    </testItem>
  </children>
</testItem>
<testItem name="TestSuite2" enabled="false">
  <children>
    <testItem name="test3" enabled="false">
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="test4" enabled="false">
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="test5" enabled="false">
    </testItem>
  </children>
</testItem>
```

Scenario:
1. suiteToEnable='test1' => test1, TestSuite1 become true

2. suiteToEnable='testX' => testX, test2 and TestSuite1 become true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modified after clarifying comment]

The following code sets the enabled attributes to true and prints out the resulting string:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def str = '''\
<testItems>
  <children>
    <testItem name="TestSuite1" enabled="false">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test1" enabled="false">
        </testItem>
        <testItem name="test2" enabled="false">
        </testItem>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false">
        </testItem>
      </children>
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="TestSuite2" enabled="false">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false">
        </testItem>
        <testItem name="test4" enabled="false">
        </testItem>
        <testItem name="test5" enabled="false">
        </testItem>
      </children>
    </testItem>
  </children>
</testItems>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(str)

def suiteToEnable = 'TestSuite2'

xml.'**'.find { 
  it.name() == 'testItem' && it.@name == suiteToEnable
}.'**'.findAll { 
  it.name() == 'testItem'
}*.@enabled = 'true'

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testItems>
  <children>
    <testItem name="TestSuite1" enabled="false">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test1" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test2" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false"/>
      </children>
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="TestSuite2" enabled="true">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="true"/>
        <testItem name="test4" enabled="true"/>
        <testItem name="test5" enabled="true"/>
      </children>
    </testItem>
  </children>
</testItems>
```

this uses the groovy [depthFirst alias **](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_flexible_navigation_with_children_depthfirst_and_breadthfirst), and the [spread operator `*.`](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator).

[addendum after question in comment]

for your second question of only enabling one child and its grand parent we can do:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(str)

def suiteToEnable = 'test2'

def item = xml.'**'.find { 
  it.name() == 'testItem' && it.@name == suiteToEnable
}
item.@enabled = 'true'
item.parent().parent().@enabled = 'true'

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testItems>
  <children>
    <testItem name="TestSuite1" enabled="true">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test1" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test2" enabled="true"/>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false"/>
      </children>
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="TestSuite2" enabled="false">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test4" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test5" enabled="false"/>
      </children>
    </testItem>
  </children>
</testItems>
```

[addendum 2 after another question in the comments]

the following code first finds a specific node and then sets all parent nodes with element name `testItem` to `enabled="true"`:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(str)
def suiteToEnable = 'testX'

// first find our target node
def item = xml.'**'.find { 
  it.name() == 'testItem' && it.@name == suiteToEnable
}

// then get the parents recursively, find all parents called
// 'testItem' and set them to enabled = 'true'
getParents(item).findAll { it.name() == 'testItem' }.each { 
  it.@enabled = 'true' 
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)

// recursively get parents of node using the '..' alias for 
// the node.parent() call
def getParents(node) {
  (node.is(node.'..') ? [] : getParents(node.'..')) + [node]
}
```

prints out:

```
<testItems>
  <children>
    <testItem name="TestSuite1" enabled="true">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test1" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test2" enabled="true">
          <children>
            <testItem name="testX" enabled="true"/>
          </children>
        </testItem>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false"/>
      </children>
    </testItem>
    <testItem name="TestSuite2" enabled="false">
      <children>
        <testItem name="test3" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test4" enabled="false"/>
        <testItem name="test5" enabled="false"/>
      </children>
    </testItem>
  </children>
</testItems>
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected, this just enables / disables ALL test items. I want that, when given a test item name, I enable it and all its children, e.g. parameterGiven=TestSuite1 => TestSuite1, test1,test2,test3 are true and all the other are false

Comment: my bad, I've fixed the solution to better match the question

Comment: Do you think I could modify your code to also enable the parents of suite to enable? For example, if suiteToEnable = test2 I would want test2 to be true and also TestSuite1 (its parent) to be true.

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies I've added a second code snippet which does selective child-grandparent modification as per your last comment.

Comment: I know I'm overstepping my boundaries and I can't express how much I appreciate your help, but do you think you could modify the last snippet to work for an indefinite number of parents? Supposing test2 has a testItem child testX and suiteToEnable='testX' => testX, test2 and TestSuite1 become 3. If suiteToEnable='test1' however, only test1 nad TestSuite1 become true. I'll add another xml snippet in the question. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies another snippet added.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! You're truly one of a kind!